# Is it possible to generalise equations in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Apologies for my poor wording of the question. I've tried searching for an answer but not knowing what to search is making it very difficult to find one.

Here is a simple function which calculates the area of a triangle.

```
triangleArea        :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Float
triangleArea a b c 
    | (a + b) <= c  = error "Not a triangle!"
    | (a + c) <= b  = error "Not a triangle!"
    | (b + c) <= a  = error "Not a triangle!"
    | otherwise     = sqrt (s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c))
        where s     = (a + b + c) / 2
```

Three lines of the function have been taken up for the purposes of error checking. I was wondering if these three lines could be condensed into one generic line.

I was wondering if something similar to the following would be possible

```
(arg1 + arg2) == arg3
```

where Haskell knows to check each possible combination of the three arguments.

Comment: Well, you could write `any [ arg1 + arg2 <= arg3 | [arg1, arg2, arg3] <- permutations [a, b, c] ]` but that actually does more work than your original code (it doesn't assume `+` commutes).

Comment: your 3 conditions are equivalent to `a + b + c <= 2 * maximum [a, b, c]`

Comment: @behzad.nouri You could post an answer with that.

Comment: On the risk of being obvious: what's wrong with `triangleArea a b c` 
      `| (a+b)<=c || (a+c)<=b || (b+c)<=a  = error "Not a triangle!"`   `|otherwise  = ...`?

Answer (score 5):

I think @behzad.nouri's comment is the best.  Sometimes doing a little math is the best way to program.  Here's a somewhat overdone expansion on @melpomene's solution, which I thought would be fun to share.  Let's write a function similar to `permutations` but that computes combinations:

```
import Control.Arrow (first, second)

-- choose n xs returns a list of tuples, the first component of each having
-- n elements and the second component having the rest, in all combinations
-- (ignoring order within the lists). N.B. this would be faster if implemented
-- using a DList.
choose :: Int -> [a] -> [([a],[a])]
choose 0 xs = [([], xs)]
choose _ [] = []
choose n (x:xs) =
  map (first (x:)) (choose (n-1) xs) ++
  map (second (x:)) (choose n xs)
```

So..

```
ghci> choose 2 [1,2,3]
[([1,2],[3]),([1,3],[2]),([2,3],[1])]
```

Now you can write

```
triangleArea a b c
  | or [ x + y <= z | ([x,y], [z]) <- choose 2 [a,b,c] ] = error ...
```

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't address the question of how to shorten your error checking code, but you may be able to limit how often you repeat it by defining some new types with invariants. This function needs error checking because you can't trust the user to supply `Float` triples that make a reasonable triangle, and if you continue to define functions this way then every triangle-related function you write would need similar error checks.

However, if you define a Triangle type, you can check your invariants only once, when a triangle is created, and then all other functions will be guaranteed to receive valid triangles:

```
module Triangle (Triangle(), mkTriangle, area) where

data Triangle a = Triangle a a a deriving Show

mkTriangle :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> a -> a -> Either String (Triangle a)
mkTriangle a b c
  | a + b <= c = wrong
  | a + c <= b = wrong
  | b + c <= a = wrong
  | otherwise  = Right $ Triangle a b c
  where wrong  = Left "Not a triangle!"

area :: Floating a => Triangle a -> a
area (Triangle a b c) = sqrt (s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c))
  where s = (a + b + c) / 2
```

Here we export the Triangle type, but not its constructor, so that the client must use `mkTriangle` instead, which can do the required error checking. Then `area`, and any other triangle functions you write, can omit the checks that they are receiving a valid triangle. This general pattern is called "smart constructors".

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ideas.

1. Using existing tools, you can generate all the permutations of the arguments and check that they all satisfy a condition. Thus:

   ```
   import Data.List
   triangleArea a b c
       | any (\[x, y, z] -> x + y <= z) (permutations [a,b,c])
                   = error "Not a triangle!"
       | otherwise = {- ... -}
   ```

   This doesn't require writing very much additional code; however, it will search some permutations you don't care about.
2. Use the usual trick for choosing an element from a list and the left-overs. The `zippers` function is one I use frequently:

   ```
   zippers :: [a] -> [([a], a, [a])]
   zippers = go [] where
       go b [] = []
       go b (v:e) = (b, v, e) : go (v:b) e
   ```

   We can use it to build a function which chooses only appropriate triples of elements:

   ```
   triples :: [a] -> [(a, a, a)]
   triples xs = do
       (b1, v1, e1) <- zippers xs
       (b2, v2, e2) <- zippers e1
       v3 <- b1 ++ b2 ++ e2
       return (v1, v2, v3)
   ```

   Now we can write our guard like in part (1), but it will only consider unique pairings for the addition.

   ```
   triangleArea a b c
       | any (\(x, y, z) -> x + y <= z) (triples [a,b,c])
                   = error "Not a triangle!"
       | otherwise = {- ... -}
   ```